# How to increase the number of parallel Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task

I'm writing a small desktop client to download the list of files,
I'm using the separate Task for each download, and when i run in my system it always runs maximum of 2 downloads parallel. I'm using Core I7 processor with 64 bit OS

Is there any way i can forcefully increase my parallel downloads (i.e. `MinimumDegreeOfParallelism` like `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`), or is there any other way to achieve it, I need at least 4 files to be downloaded in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of parallel downloads is probably not limited by the number of concurrent threads, but by the number of concurrent connections made by your application, which is by default limited to 2.
You can change this value by modifying the [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property, for example:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks @Adi Lester for the response

Comment: Just curios to understand more about tasks, If I set my ServiceManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 1, and i started two or more tasks in application. now both the tasks are getting started, and downloads are happening only from Task 1, when i debug and see the Status property of Task (both task1 & task 2 are in running state), But task 2 is neither throwing error that i don't have additional connection and neither not downloading until the connection is available. So what is the state of this Task2 ? (does't goes to sleep mode or poling to  get the connection)

Comment: @Mathiyazhagan Task2 is running, but blocks until a connection is available. Whether it yields the CPU time to other threads during that time depends on .NET's implementation, which I have no knowledge of.